# Why does path not fit inside SVG viewbox?

Tags: javascript, html, web, svg, viewbox

[image][image]

**Expected Behavior:**
Icon to fit only the area of the 24 x 24 viewbox.

**Actual Behavior:**
The svg tag takes up the correct area of 24 x 24 but the path element is not contained inside of the 24 x 24 area.

How would I be able to have the path be constrained to the 24 x 24 area and not go over? Currently this is what my svg tag looks like.

```html
<a href="#">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
       <path d="M15.99 2a13.99 13.99 0 0 0-5.1 27.03c-.13-1.11-.23-2.81.05-4.02l1.64-6.96s-.41-.84-.41-2.07c0-1.95 1.13-3.4 2.53-3.4 1.2 0 1.77.9 1.77 1.97 0 1.2-.76 2.99-1.16 4.66-.33 1.39.7 2.53 2.07 2.53 2.49 0 4.4-2.63 4.4-6.4 0-3.35-2.41-5.69-5.85-5.69a6.05 6.05 0 0 0-6.32 6.07c0 1.2.46 2.49 1.04 3.19.12.14.13.26.09.4l-.39 1.59c-.06.25-.21.31-.47.18-1.73-.83-2.81-3.39-2.81-5.44 0-4.41 3.2-8.47 9.25-8.47 4.85 0 8.63 3.46 8.63 8.09 0 4.83-3.04 8.71-7.26 8.71-1.42 0-2.75-.74-3.2-1.61l-.88 3.33a15 15 0 0 1-1.74 3.67A13.97 13.97 0 0 0 30 16.01 14.02 14.02 0 0 0 15.99 2z">
       </path>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, the viewBox doesn't have to match your dimensions, so adjust your viewBox - that's what it's there for! The viewBox settings below seems to work. (I scaled up the SVG size and added a 1px border red to show the effect).

```css
svg {
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="240px" height="240px" viewBox="1.6 2 28.73 27.99">
       <path d="M15.99 2a13.99 13.99 0 0 0-5.1 27.03c-.13-1.11-.23-2.81.05-4.02l1.64-6.96s-.41-.84-.41-2.07c0-1.95 1.13-3.4 2.53-3.4 1.2 0 1.77.9 1.77 1.97 0 1.2-.76 2.99-1.16 4.66-.33 1.39.7 2.53 2.07 2.53 2.49 0 4.4-2.63 4.4-6.4 0-3.35-2.41-5.69-5.85-5.69a6.05 6.05 0 0 0-6.32 6.07c0 1.2.46 2.49 1.04 3.19.12.14.13.26.09.4l-.39 1.59c-.06.25-.21.31-.47.18-1.73-.83-2.81-3.39-2.81-5.44 0-4.41 3.2-8.47 9.25-8.47 4.85 0 8.63 3.46 8.63 8.09 0 4.83-3.04 8.71-7.26 8.71-1.42 0-2.75-.74-3.2-1.61l-.88 3.33a15 15 0 0 1-1.74 3.67A13.97 13.97 0 0 0 30 16.01 14.02 14.02 0 0 0 15.99 2z">
       </path>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. How did you come up with the values for the viewBox?

Comment: Threw it into codepen and tweaked it until it fit. It's hard to do it from just looking at the path because of the arc commands. One of the variety of getboundingbox would have worked programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with your SVG path. It is bleeding outside the view box. This is what it looks like in Illustrator:

[image]

This is after editing the path in illustrator to contain it to the view box:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path d="M12 0C5.4 0 0 5.3 0 11.9c0 5 3 9.4 7.6 11.2-.1-1-.2-2.4 0-3.4l1.4-6s-.4-.7-.4-1.8c0-1.7 1-2.9 2.2-2.9 1 0 1.5.8 1.5 1.7 0 1-.7 2.6-1 4-.3 1.2.6 2.2 1.8 2.2 2.1 0 3.8-2.3 3.8-5.5 0-2.9-2.1-4.9-5-4.9-2.9-.1-5.3 2.1-5.4 4.9v.3c0 1 .4 2.1.9 2.7.1.1.1.2.1.3l-.3 1.4c-.1.2-.2.3-.4.2-1.5-.7-2.4-2.9-2.4-4.7 0-3.8 2.7-7.3 7.9-7.3 4.2 0 7.4 3 7.4 6.9 0 4.1-2.6 7.5-6.2 7.5-1.2 0-2.4-.6-2.7-1.4l-.8 3c-.4 1.1-.9 2.2-1.5 3.1 6.3 2 13-1.6 15-7.9.4-1.2.5-2.4.5-3.6C24 5.4 18.6 0 12 0z"/>
      </path>
    </svg>
</a>
```

Also, adding `display: inline-block` to your anchor tag allows the SVG to take up it's space.